# Docker and .bash_history

Tags: bash, docker, ipython, dockerfile

Is there any way to share a `.bash_history` volume with a docker container so that everytime I go into a shell I have my bash history available for scrolling through?

Would be awesome to be able to do the same thing with IPython too.

Answer (score 28):

It is the example from the [documentation about volume: *Mount a host file as a data volume*](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/#/mount-a-host-file-as-a-data-volume):

```
docker run --rm -it -v ~/.bash_history:/root/.bash_history ubuntu /bin/bash
```

> This will drop you into a bash shell in a new container, you will have your **bash history from the host** and when you exit the container, the host will have the history of the commands typed while in the container.

Comment: I should have added a comment on this - I saw this and tried it, but with no success. It seems that the commands I run inside the container do not update the `.bash_history` file. I am running the commands inside the container as the root user. Any idea?

Comment: Is it the same user on the host and in the container ?

Comment: No, the user on my host is my user, and the user inside the container is root. But I don't think that should change anything? When I am inside the container, it seems that there is no .bash_history file anywhere being written to when I execute commands.

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu in your host ? https://forums.docker.com/t/how-to-save-the-last-bash-session/162

Comment: Well, with Ubuntu 14.04, I tested as in the doc I referenced, and I do not find my `mkdir junk` and anyway, my history is empty, so the doc should be updated I think.

Comment: There is indeed a typo in the documentation. `.bash_history` should be in the users's home directory, not the root of the fs. Should be `docker run --rm -it -v ~/.bash_history:/root/.bash_history ubuntu /bin/bash` as we are root in docker containers by default.

Comment: Mostly irrelevant, but I didn't want to share bash history, just needed to take host terminal history to a container, so taking clue from here & extending it further, I used a separate `.docker_bash_history` and mounted that in the same way as you've mentioned.

Comment: @0xc0de your use case sounds same as mine. I want my local command history in the container, but not the other way around. Did you successfully do this by copying `~/.bash_history` into the container? If not, can you explain what you did that worked?

Comment: @cryanbhu You can make a copy of .bash_history file and pass that to the container `docker run --rm -it -v ~/.bash_history:/root/.docker_bash_history ubuntu /bin/bash`. Copying history file can be automated if it's a repetitive (be careful not to overwrite history updated by the container).

Comment: yup, i found the solution but in a slightly different way. I copied a script of my wanted commands into the container, and made the container look at it for history. `COPY commands_script.sh myf/my_history`  
`ENV HISTFILE myf/my_history`  
`RUN PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a; history -r"`

Comment: Be careful guys! I mounted my 4000+ lines long history file to a container, where it was cropped to 500 lines immediately becouse HISTSIZE was exactly that number, no way to recover it, I just lost ~90% percent of my bash history :D

Answer (score 11):

In your [`docker-compose.override.yml`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/#/understanding-multiple-compose-files):

```
version: '2'
services:
  whatever:
    …
    volumes:
      - …
      - ~/.bash_history:/root/.bash_history
```

Comment: The documentation states that mounted volumes have to start with '/'. It doesn't work for me with '~'.

Comment: @aghull you can replace `~` by the value of `$HOME`, but it will be less portable

Comment: It doesn't allow me to mount a single file!

Answer (score 6):

To keep IPython history, you can set the `IPYTHONDIR` environment variable to somewhere within your mapped volume.

The `docker-compose.override.yml` would look like this:

```
version: '2'
services:
  some-service:
    environment:
      - IPYTHONDIR=/app/.ipython
    volumes:
      - .:/app
```

Answer (score 2):

My solution is useful when:

- you don't want to share your local `.bash_history` with `.bash_history` in your container
- you use other shell (like fish shell) but you want to save `.bash_history` between your builds
- you don't want to commit `.bash_history` to git repo but you want to create it  automatically inside same directory when a container starts

I assume file structure to be:

```
docker-compose.yml
docker/
   \--> bash/
      \--> .bashrc
      \--> .bash_history
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
web-service:
  build: .
  volumes:
  - ./docker/bash/.bashrc:/home/YOUR_USER_NAME/.bashrc
  - ./docker/bash:/home/YOUR_USER_NAME/bash
```

**./docker/bash/.bashrc** - it will automatically create .bash_history:

```
export HISTFILE=~/bash/.bash_history
touch $HISTFILE
```

Optionally, you can add to **.gitignore**:

```
docker/bash/.bash_history
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also achieve this with a named volume and tell bash where he can find the bash history file by defining the `HISTFILE` environment variable. I explained a bit more here:
https://antistatique.net/en/we/blog/2019/11/12/tips-docker-keep-your-bash-history

Comment: Just an observation for those who are not using root user in the docker container. You need to modify your Dockerfile in order to create the folder where the bash_history file is located and change the ownership of this folder to the user you are using in the container.

Answer (score 0):

For bash

```
volumes:
        - ./.data/shell_history/php_bash_history.txt:/home/www-data/.bash_history #bash
```

For sh

```
volumes:
    - ./.data/shell_history/nginx_bash_history.txt:/root/.ash_history #sh
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a .bash_history file in my project root containing useful commands that I copy to the docker container. I can then access the commands using the up and down arrow keys when I am inside the container or inside a vscode devcontainer.

I have these lines in my **Dockerfile**

```
ENV HISTFILE=/home/vscode/.bash_history
COPY .bash_history /home/vscode/
```

Your docker container home directory may not be `/home/vscode/`. To verify what your home directory is, you can run the command `echo $HOME` from inside your container.

One other thing to note, which I was a little surprised by, is that it seems that the .bash_history file needs an empty line at the end of the file in order for this to work.