# How to enable CLI history in docker container?

Tags: linux, docker, command-line-interface, command-prompt

In our company we use docker containers to develop and maintain Magento site. Our workstations run Ubuntu 16.04. I would like to have command line history persistent between docker containers runs (between `docker-compose stop` and `docker-compose up`). I would like to be able to evoke commands from last container run.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28279862/docker-and-bash-history/28280132#28280132 ?